# OLS polynomial with data skips

Tags: least-squares, polynomial

I have the  following problem:

There is a data flow, which sequentially sends numbers:
For example: `1 3 5 7 9 11 13`, and I want to approximate it with a polynomial of a 
 degree  `n` assigning the position of the number as `x` and the number itself as `f(x)`. So with the the example above  it  would be `f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3,  f(3) = 5` and so on.  and with `n = 2` we get  accurate prediction `f(x) = 0*x^2 + 2*x - 1`

However, data flow is not robust and sometimes it doesn't deliver us a number,  (each number  can be  skipped with a  probability `p`), and we get  `1 3 7 9 11 13` and predicted  polynomial shifts left, the error  is accumulated till the end of the flow and it starts to be very inncacurate.

Is there any model which can count possible data skips to restore them?